# How to specify the dispatcher type for a filter defined in a Guice Servlet Module?

Tags: java, guice, servlet-filters, guice-servlet

I'm working on a Java based web app. We're using `Guice` and its `ServletModule` to configure servlets and filters.

Now, I need a `Filter` to be invoked even when a request is forwarded through the dispatcher, not only on incoming requests.

In a plain JEE web app I would probably set my `web.xml` this way...

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>SomeFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.acme.SomeFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SomeFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

However I'm not able to do the same in Guice, where I only can write something like that...

```
filter("/*").through(com.acme.SomeFilter.class);
```

...and it seems to me I cannot explicitly specify the `FORWARD` mode. So the filter does not kick in when a request is forwarded.

Do you know if there's a way I can accomplish that in Guice ?

thanks in advance.